# Get tsv file with header using sed

Tags: csv, sed

So I wrote this sed commands to get .tsv files filtered (in this case) by chromosome 19. Unfortunatley i dont know how to get the Header for the tsv file as well. So far i only get headerless data. how should I modify my code?

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/dataset.tsv.bgz -O temp.data.99.tsv.bgz
gunzip -c temp.data.99.tsv.bgz > temp.data.99.tsv 
sed -n '/^19:/p' temp.data.99.tsv | sed 's/:/   /g' > finished_tsv_files/temp.data.99_Chr_19.tsv
rm temp.data.99.tsv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
/^19:/p
```

with

```
1p; /^19:/p
```

to output first line, too.